# visual mode substitiute in vscode vim

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I have the following in a text file:

```
<Location>ame<Location>
<Title>Kill-A-Watt Meter<Title>
<Type>for sale by owner<Type>
<Category>electronics - by owner<Category>
<Email>youremail@gmail.com<Email>
<Street>My Street<Street>
```

I ant to change the second tags in each line to closing html tags. eg change

```
<Location>ame<Location>
```

to

```
<Location>ame</Location>
```

After selecting the entire block in visual mode I tried:

```
:<>/s/[a-z]</[a-z]</
```

Nothing is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the given text a possible substitution is:

```
:'<,'>s/.*<\zs\.*/\\&
```

explanation:

```
:'<,'>s                 use last selected visual area for substitution. More info in: help '<
       /.*<\zs\.*       match every character after the last '<'. More info in: help \zs
                 /\\&   prepend matched text with a backslash. Here '&' means matched text. More info in: help s/\&
```